# Upload File in Signup form Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, attachment, sign, odoo-12

Iam trying to add a field "attachment" into the Signup form of Odoo 12. I share with you my work if you can correct me please :

In my file_one.xml :

```
<template id="auth_signup_fields_extend" inherit_id="auth_signup.fields" name="Signup Fields Extend">
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('field-confirm_password')]" position="after">
<div class="form-group field-attachment">
<label for="attachment" class="control-label">Attachment</label>
<input type="file" name="attachment"  multiple="true" data-show-upload="true" data-show- 
caption="true" id="project.id" data-show-preview="true" class="form-control" required="required" t- 
att-readonly="'readonly' if only_passwords else None" t-att-autofocus="'autofocus' if login and not 
only_passwords else None"/>
</div>
</xpath>
</template>
```

In my file_2.xml :

```
<data>
<record id="res_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit</field>
<field name="model">res.partner</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<xpath expr="//field[@name='function']" position="after">
<field name="attachment"/>
</xpath>
</field>
</record>
</data>
```

In my model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, models

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    attachment = fields.Binary(string='File of User',attachment=True)
```

In my file controller.py :

```
@http.route('/web/signup', type='http', auth='public', website=True, 
sitemap=False)
def web_auth_signup(self,**post):
    qcontext = self.get_auth_signup_qcontext()
    values = {}
    if post.get('attachment',False):
        Attachments = request.env['ir.attachment']
        name = post.get('attachment').filename      
        file = post.get('attachment')
        project_id = post.get('project_id')
        attachment = file.read() 
        attachment_id = Attachments.sudo().create({
            'name':name,
            'datas_fname': name,
            'res_name': name,
            'type': 'binary',   
            'res_model': 'model.model',
            'datas': attachment.encode('base64'),
        })
        value = {
            'attachment' : attachment_id
        }
        return request.render("fl_auth_signup.users", value)
```

I saw many tutorials and questions/answers about that but my module doesn't work, for now, i have the error : local variable 'Attachments' referenced before assignment

Please, help, can you correct me? ...

Comment: Please show the last lines of the error log. You can't have that error in the controller.

Comment: Hi @Kenly, iam working with Windows10, when i try to access to the page : localhost:8069/web/signup, i can't because i have this error : " local variable 'Attachments' referenced before assignment" , please help !!!!

Comment: Try to find out which line generates this error. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.log` and look for a line containing `referenced before assignment`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me, that is :   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0e\server\odoo\addons\fl_auth_signup\controllers\main.py", line 43, in web_auth_signup
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Attachments' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please provide the code of `web_auth_signup` in `fl_auth_signup\controllers\main.py`

Comment: Hi Kenly, i pushed my repository in Github, you can see here the main.py : https://github.com/dalilahannouche/fl_auth_signup/blob/master/controllers/main.py

Comment: You can't have that error using the code in the repository above, Maybe `Attachments = request.env['ir.attachment']` was removed. Try to restart the Odoo server or try to declare `Attachments ` before the line indicated in the error log.

Comment: I tried again and again, i really don't know what to do, seriously i need help @Kenly ... Can you help me in the repository that i shared with you ?

Comment: Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the following error:

```
local variable 'attachment_id' referenced before assignment , line 52, in web_auth_signup
```

This error will occurs because the following code should be inside `if` statement:

```
value = {'attachment': attachment_id}

return request.render("fl_auth_signup.users", value)
```

You also used `*args` and `**kw` (at line `75`) but they are not declared:

```
return super(AuthSignupHome, self).web_login(*args, **kw)
```

I checked the original code in `auth_signup` and I found that you changed the signature of the `web_auth_signup` method. I suggest you keep the signature as it is and use `kw` instead of `post`.

```
@http.route('/web/signup', type='http', auth='public', website=True,
            sitemap=False)
def web_auth_signup(self, *args, **kw):
    qcontext = self.get_auth_signup_qcontext()
    # values = {}
    if kw.get('attachment', False):
        attachments = request.env['ir.attachment']
        name = kw.get('attachment').filename
        file = kw.get('attachment')
        # project_id = kw.get('project_id')
        attachment = file.read()
        attachment_id = attachments.sudo().create({
            'name': name,
            'datas_fname': name,
            'res_name': name,
            'type': 'binary',
            'res_model': 'model.model',
            'datas': base64.b64encode(attachment),
        })
        value = {
            'attachment': attachment_id
        }
        return request.render("fl_auth_signup.users", value)

        # The rest of your code with no changes
```

Update the `form` tag and set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`, it is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control.

```
<template id="new_signup" inherit_id="auth_signup.signup" name="New Sign up login">
    <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="enctype">multipart/form-data</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer helped you?

Comment: I am glad to help